# [PHCollectionList canContainCustomKeyAssets]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

Fetching PHAssets is now crashing for me on latest versions of iOS (iOS 9.2 and iOS 9.3). It previously worked fine.

The error I am getting is:

> [PHCollectionList canContainCustomKeyAssets]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

The line throwing the exception is:

```
            PHFetchResult *fetchImage = [PHAsset fetchKeyAssetsInAssetCollection:(PHAssetCollection*)collection options:fetchOptions];
```

Here is more code, for reference:

```
Class PHPhotoLibrary_class = NSClassFromString(@"PHPhotoLibrary");
        if (PHPhotoLibrary_class) {

            PHFetchResult *fetchResult = self.collectionsFetchResults[indexPath.section];
            PHCollection *collection = fetchResult[indexPath.row];

            cell.textLabel.text = collection.localizedTitle;

            PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
            PHFetchResult *fetchImage = [PHAsset fetchKeyAssetsInAssetCollection:(PHAssetCollection*)collection options:fetchOptions];
            PHAsset *asset = [fetchImage firstObject];

            PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;

            CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
            CGFloat dimension = 90.0;
            CGSize size = CGSizeMake(dimension*scale, dimension*scale);

            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset
                                                       targetSize:size
                                                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                          options:options
                                                    resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                        if (result) {
                                                            CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
                                                            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, 2);
                                                            CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                                                            [result drawInRect:imageRect];
                                                            cell.imageView.image  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                                                            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                                                        }
                                                        else{
                                                            UIImage *placeholder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-placeholder.jpg"];
                                                            CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
                                                            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, 2);
                                                            CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                                                            [placeholder drawInRect:imageRect];
                                                            cell.imageView.image  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                                                            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                                                        }
                                                    }];
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue actually lies here:

```
PHCollection *collection = fetchResult[indexPath.row];
```

and then here:

```
PHAsset *asset = [fetchImage firstObject];
```

You are fetching the collection using `PHCollection` and then just assuming all assets are `PHAssets` without properly checking if this is the case or not.

Actually, PHCollection has [two possible subclasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHCollection_Class/): `PHAsset` and `PHCollectionList`, and the `PHCollectionList` is what is throwing the error here.

Wrap the code after `PHCollection *collection = fetchResult[indexPath.row];` with a check for `PHAsset`, and it should solve the issue:

```
if ([collection isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]]) {
//code 
}
```

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but I just had that exact exception show up in an App of mine and I was wondering if there is a reliable way of triggering this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, get all assets using PHAsset like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{     

        AllPhotos=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];
        for (PHAsset *asset in result)
        {
            [AllPhotos addObject:asset];

        }
        [self.collectionView reloadData];

        // code here
    });
```

Not, use the collectionview delegate method like

```
  PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    PHAsset *asset = [AllPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
    requestOptions.synchronous = false;

    //CGFloat scale = 1.5; //or an even smaller one
    if (!manager)
    {
        manager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
    }
    if (!requestOptions)
    {
        requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    }

    [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                       targetSize:CGSizeMake(imagesize.width,imagesize.height)
                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                          options:requestOptions
                    resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info)
     {
         [imageview setImage:image];
     }];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview];
```